# XMPPAuthentication fails for some users in Facebook iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, xmpp, facebook-chat

I am creating an iPhone application and in that i am implementing the Facebook chat feature using Graph API and XMPP. It is working fine and I can chat. But the issue is, XMPP is not get authenticated for some users, whose online presence showing as mobile device icon in browser. Means in the Facebook web app, those friend's online status shows like a mobile device, not as normal green icon. I checked those accounts and the users are not logged in the mobile and only on the web app. is there any possible reason for this issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure you are using the right authentication method on Facebook. If you use a proxy (or traffic get through your own server), you will need to implement X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM auth method.
You also need to make sure your traffic is encrypted (SSL/TLS)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM auth method for login in the app. So should I check the traffic in the internet connection? Or some other places? And for the app, we are not using any server side support for login.